# object reference through variable, like: $object->$ref

Tags: php, stdclass

I want to reference an attribute in a object dynamically, as not all of my objects have the same attributes, like:

```
if ($person->$status) {
    //do this
}
```

Person is a stdClass Object:

```
stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => name
                        [silver] => 214321
                        [gold] => 334532
                    )
```

the variable $status in my example above could be the string value "silver" or "gold" or any other value and I want to check whether the object has an attribute with that value or not.

The example above is not exactly my case, I just created it to demonstrate my problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `property_exists` method to check whether a property is present in the object:

```
if(property_exists($person, $status)) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `get_object_vars` to get an array of the object's accessible properties:

```
$person_array = get_object_vars($person_object);
if ($person_array[$status]) {
    // do this
}
```